# OS X resets Perferred Startup OS / Partition

Tags: windows-7, macos, osx-snow-leopard

So I bought a MacBook Pro and because I prefer it, and need it I have Windows 7(x64) installed using BootCamp.

My problem is that on the rare occasions that I boot into OS X it changed OS X to be the default startup OS. I have to reset it to Windows 7 each time.

Is there a fix to this? Or a script that I can make run on OS X startup to reset it? And how do I make a script run at startup?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I recall this being a problem that was fixed with a patch. Hit up Apple's forums to have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/). It's a bootloader that installs on your OS X partition. In the file `/efi/refit/refit.conf`, there is a section that reads:

```
# List legacy options first. When enabled, legacy BIOS based boot options
# (e.g. Windows, Linux via LILO or GRUB) will be listed first. This is
# intended as a quick fix to change the default boot choice until full
# configurability arrives.
#
#legacyfirst

# Set the default menu selection.  The available arguments match the
# keyboard accelerators available within rEFIt.  You may select the default
# loader using a one-character abbreviation for the OS name ("M" = Mac OS X,
# "L" = Linux, "W" = Windows).  You may also specify a digit between 1 and
# 9, in which case the Nth loader in the menu will be the default.  You can
# also select a rEFIt tool entry ("S" = EFI Shell, "P" = Partitioning Tool,
# "U" = shutdown).  This is intended as a quick fix to change the default
# boot choice until full configurability arrives.
#
#default_selection L
```

Uncommenting either `legacyfirst` or setting `default_selection W` should work. I have not tried this although I use rEFIt without any problems. In the same file, you can change the `timeout 20` line to something shorter as well.

[image: rEFIt]

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a way to make rEFIt only appear on if i press the alt key like the normal bootloader?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. You can set the time to a very short interval instead. If you press alt, you will get the normal bootloader, but the OS X selection will now say *rEFIt*.

Comment: Ok thanks, its not perfect but its good enough, until i just remove OS X anyway

Answer (score 1):

How are you booting into OS X?  If you use the Boot Camp control panel to select OS X, it makes that a permanent setting in the firmware (i.e. it'll boot OS X until you tell it different).  If you just want to boot OS X once, it's easier to hold the Option key at boot -- this selects the firmware-based startup manager, which'll let you select which volume to boot from without changing the permanent setting.

Comment: I am doing the second method which does seem to be pernament for me