# How to Get OSX Startup Manager to Appear Every Time?

Tags: macos, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OS X resets Perferred Startup OS / Partition](https://superuser.com/questions/188615/os-x-resets-perferred-startup-os-partition)

Is there any way to get the OSX Startup Manager to appear on every boot?  I hate having to hold the Option key, especially if Windows is processing some update on shutdown and I have no idea how long it will take.  Is there any way to set this?

Ideally, it would come up and wait for something like 60 seconds, and if you don't do anything, it will use the default boot partition.

Thanks!